# `FileNotFoundException` when running test(s) in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, mstest

I upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 after using VS 2012.
In VS 2012, when created new Test Project and add files to be "Copy Always" the visual studio copied them into bin/debug and while running the current directory(Environment.CurrentDirectory) was "bin/debug".
In VS 2013 the current directory is "TestResults/something+guid" and VS 2013 is not copying the files to this folder so an "file not found" exception thrown.
How do I change back the current directory to bin/debug in VS2013 to be like VS 2012?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running a unit test project?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to handle this scenario is to use [`DeploymentItemAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx) or test settings config to include the file(s) you want. It is this way because not all tests require the same files, different tests may require different configs entirely, or you may have several test runs and would need to inspect test artifacts to understand why one run failed and another succeeded (where the only difference was a referenced assembly, or a loose file.) Further, when run in a hosted environment (Team Foundation Server, for example) this same pattern is used on the agent server(s), writing a test to set current directory would fail when run on something like a TFS test agent.

As an aside, the path you see during a test is not actually VS2013, it's the MS Test Agent itself (a second process runs tests for sandboxing purposes, I beleive it has been this was since VS2010.)

It sounds like you have an additional problem, all but guaranteed to be one of the following. Without seeing the exception detail I'm making a best guess, these are in order of likelihood:

1. You have a loose file such as "test.txt" **included in your test project** and you have a `DeploymentItemAttribute` decorating your test method. But the "Copy to output folder" setting for "test.txt" is set to "**Do not copy**".

   *Changing this setting, rebuilding, then retesting should work.*
2. You have a missing assembly reference, likely for a non-BCL assembly (or, more specifically, you're missing a reference to an assembly which is referenced by an assembly you are referencing.)

   *To fix this problem you should load [`fuslogvw.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx) and use the log data to discover any missing assembly reference(s) to your test project.*
3. You have referenced a native DLL or assembly which is compiled for a specific processor architecture (x86 vs x64 vs MSIL) and it cannot be loaded within the processor architecture which MS Test Agent is running.

   *The solution to this is to use an assembly with the correct processor architecture when running the test.*

Between project references, "Copy to output directory" setting, and `[DeploymentItem]`, your tests should be finding the file(s) they rely on.

Let me know if you need more info, if you're still having a problem i would suggest editing the question to include the exception detail (or at least the parts that matter, such as `Type`, `Message` and the first 5 lines of `StackTrace`.)

Comment: I used DeploymentItemAttribute and the same exception thrown. Can I open test setting to one project and not to the entire solution?

Comment: test settings are solution-wide to control limited behavior at a higher level, if you need more granular control you have to use various test attributes. also, a "content file" for a referenced assembly is not automatically copied, you also need to reference the content file(s) from your test project(s) and set their "copy to output folder" option in the test project as well. This is by design.

Comment: @NivNavick Did you check if the file(s) you have specified using [DeploymentItem] has been deployed to the "TestResults/something+guid" folder? I'm asking because if you are using wrong source path in [DeploymentItem] you will not get any error messages.

Comment: @NivNavick Could you post an example how you are using [DeploymentItem]?